# Do you have any idea or documentation about why we have arc4random_stir() in swift?

Tags: swift

I have written the program below for generating random unique numbers for several number of times by invoking the function, but it seems like I'm getting the same pattern with minimal changes.

```
func generateRandom(withinNumber: Int)  {

   var i:Int = 0
   var elements = Set<Int>()

   while i != withinNumber {
      let num:Int = Int(arc4random())%withinNumber + 1
      if elements.count <= withinNumber && elements.contains(num) == false {
         elements.insert(num)
      }
      else {
         i = i-1
      }

      i=i+1
   }    
   print(elements)    
   elements.removeAll()    
}

generateRandom(withinNumber: 10)
```

How does I make my program effectively run to generate several random unique numbers.

Please let me know it would be very helpful for me.

Comment: What makes you think you need to do anything with `stir`?

Comment: Initially, I thought it may be helpful in generating unique random numbers. And I was trying to make it work with different programming steps but i didn't understood its functionality...Please let me know. Thanks in advance

Comment: You shouldn't need it.  Current man-pages don't even show it, and the [archived legacy man-pages](https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man3/arc4random_stir.3.html) say "The arc4random_stir() function reads data from /dev/urandom and uses it to permute the S-Boxes via arc4random_addrandom().   There is no need to call arc4random_stir() before using arc4random() functions family, since they automatically initialize themselves."

Answer (score 2):

You are storing your numbers in a `Set` and sets are not ordered, so the order the elements are shown by `print` is unrelated to the order in which they were added to the set.

Rather the elements of a set are stored in some manner which enables fast checking for `.contains()`, and this is one reason you seeing similar sequences.

If you wish to preserve order of insertion use a collection which does this, i.e. an array. Changing to an array in your code produced the following results from 9 calls:

```
[8, 9, 7, 10, 5, 6, 2, 3, 1, 4]
[4, 9, 10, 3, 6, 2, 1, 7, 8, 5]
[8, 3, 5, 1, 6, 4, 9, 10, 7, 2]
[5, 7, 2, 9, 8, 1, 6, 10, 3, 4]
[2, 3, 7, 6, 9, 1, 8, 10, 5, 4]
[9, 10, 2, 4, 6, 8, 5, 7, 1, 3]
[9, 10, 2, 5, 4, 7, 3, 8, 1, 6]
[1, 6, 4, 5, 8, 2, 3, 9, 7, 10]
[6, 10, 5, 3, 2, 8, 1, 9, 7, 4]
```

You are also generating 10 random numbers in the range 1 to 10 and avoiding duplicates, so the results is always going to be the numbers 1 to 10 in some order.

To generate a random number in a given range do not use `%`, instead use the provided `arc4random_uniform()` which will give better a better distribution.

The function mention in your title `arc4random_stir()` is available in Swift.

BTW (*somewhat opinion based*): It is better to write `!e` (`!` being the boolean not operator) rather than `e == false`, and *never ever* write `e == true` which is the long form of `e`!

BTW (*SO etiquette*): Don't link to your code (or paste in images of it). Reduce to a small example which demonstrates the issue (not required in your case) and insert directly in the question. Keep tags minimal and appropriate. These edits were done for you this time by myself and others, you will know for next time.

HTH

Comment: I completely got it and I'm very new to Stack overflow's posting a question but anyways thank you so much. Will make sure to not repeat mistakes next time.

Comment: Do you have any idea or code samples of arc4random_stir() function.....let me know it will be ver helpful for me

Comment: All you need to do to call `arc4random_stir()` in Swift is just write it down on a line by itself. If you need its documentation type `man arc4random` in Terminal. However as the results above show there is no need for you to use this function, `arc4random` initialises itself and will produce a random sequence each run.